# Conform to Protocol and Keep Property Private

Tags: swift, architecture, protocols, private

I need to use a protocol property in the conforming class as a private. But the compiler refuses that. How can I implement that?

```
protocol ProtocolX: class {
    var x: Int { get set }

    func performAnyActionOnX()
}

extension ProtocolX {
    func performAnyActionOnX() {
        x = 5
        print(x)
    }
}

class A: ProtocolX {
    private var x:Int = 7
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: A protocol can be thought of as a contract that another type must implement. The usefulness of the protocols comes from the fact that other classes know what rules the class that adopts the protocol follows. Making the variable a `private` defeats this purpose. You need to rethink if you really need the variable to be private.

Comment: I think its very logically to be sure that a conforming class has a specific property, but I do not want this property to be appeared outside its class.

Comment: @SamehDos, in this case you need to add another layer of abstraction, some protocol that defines implementation details and not used as interface. And you can use python-like __privacy.

Answer (score 6):

As @TheAppMentor mentioned, there seems to be no exact solution to this problem as of Swift 4.

There are, however, two approximate solutions:

1.)

Since a protocol in Swift has the access level of `internal` by default, make the variable also `internal`. In order for `internal` to be enforced by the compiler, move the protocol, the class and all of their consumers (users) to a separate module (framework).

```
/* internal */ protocol ProtocolX: class {
    var x: Any { get set }

    func performAnyActionOnX()
}

extension ProtocolX {
    func performAnyActionOnX() {}
}

/* internal */ class A: ProtocolX {
    internal var x: Any = 0
}
```

2.)

Give the protocol the access level of `private` and the variable the access level of `fileprivate`. In order for the `private` protocol to be accessible, move the protocol, the class and all of their consumers to the same source file.

```
private protocol ProtocolX: class {
    var x: Any { get set }

    func performAnyActionOnX()
}

extension ProtocolX {
    func performAnyActionOnX() {}
}

class A: ProtocolX {
    fileprivate var x: Any = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since protocol's properties always have the same access level as your protocol has you can create a separate class where you can apply `fileprivate` level to them e.g.:

```swift
public class Props {
    fileprivate var x: Int = 0
}

public protocol ProtocolX: class {
    var privateProps: Props { get }
}

extension ProtocolX {
    public func performAnyActionOnX() {
        privateProps.x = 5
        print(privateProps.x)
    }
}

public class A: ProtocolX {
    public let privateProps = Props()
    
    public init() {
        privateProps.x = 7
    }
}
```

As you can see `x` has `fileprivate` access level so it can be accessible in ProtocolX extention and A class implementation only so it behaves as `private` and you can't change `privateProps` variable of class `A` and access to `x` outside:

```
let a = A()
a.performAnyActionOnX()
// Prints: 5

let x = a.privateProps.x
// error: 'x' is inaccessible due to 'fileprivate' protection level
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no the exact solution for your question, by the reason stated in the @TheAppMentor's comment. But there some workarounds which may be helpful if you purpose is to make your code understandable for humans (not to trick the compiler).

Compiles in Swift 4.0.

### Solution 1: Python-like __privacy

Fast and simple. This solution relies on the user who would agree that properties and functions starting from `_` are private and shouldn't be accessed.

```
protocol ProtocolX: class {
    // Public x
    var x: Int { get }

    // It's private!
    var _x: Int { get set }

    func performAnyActionOnX()
}

extension ProtocolX {
    var x: Int { return _x }

    func performAnyActionOnX(){
        _x = 5
        print(x)
    }
}

class A: ProtocolX {
    var _x: Int = 7
}
```

### Solution 2: Additional layer of abstration

Architecturally correct. You should split your protocol on the two parts: private and public.

```
protocol ProtocolX: class {
    var x: Int { get }

    func performAnyActionOnX()
}

protocol ProtocolXImplementation: class {
    var _x: Int { get set }
}

extension ProtocolXImplementation {    
    var x: Int { return _x }

    func performAnyActionOnX(){
        _x = 5
        print(x)
    }
}

class A: ProtocolX, ProtocolXImplementation {
    var _x: Int = 7
}

// ... somewhere later ...
// Hide the implementation when use `A`:
let item: ProtocolX = A()
```

Comment: Neither suggestion works properly, as in both cases `A()._x = 911` compiles. You can't count on a consumer to never use `_x` or `ProtocolXImplementation` directly in order to mutate.

Comment: I use this solution in my projects. Very helpful. And there are no better solution.

Comment: Well, I agree that my answer is quite unclear and understandable only by experienced users. I've added some 
 explanations.

Comment: For solution 2 how do you go about hiding the implementation when using `A`? `_x` isn't private in the A implementation.

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna, this solution could be used if you use only the public protocol (`ProtocolX`) without considering the particular implementation. For example, if you build an array `[ProtocolX]` and later will access it somewhere. Also, a protocol implementation couldn't be hidden in Swift 4, it should be public.

Comment: @kelin - Your explanations have not answered what Gary was asking about. Also, there is no pride in accepting that your answer is unclear.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh, what part exactly is unclear?